# Estimating New Hires based on Total Employment

Tags: regression, machine-learning, time-series, mathematical-statistics

I have total employment data, both history and a forecast. I also have history for newly hired and fired. For my purpose, I can assume:

```
Employment = Employment(-1) +Hired - Fired
```

My problem is that I want to estimate the number of people hired in the forecast period; I only have a forecast for the total employment.

My question is: is there some statistics procedure or optimization method I can do to use the historical data I have to converge onto a realistic solution to forecast the hired and fired data?

Comment: Just assume the constant proportion of hired to net change in employment, this will work better than anything

Comment: That was the default, thanks, do you know of any more complex ways to do it? Honestly just curious.

Comment: it depends on your data series. in my case the dumbest model is impossible to beat

Comment: You may try to solve the problem as a classification problem using  deep learning LSTM or Conv1D for example, most of the time has a more accurate result. but if you are not familiar with deep learning. I think the solution Mr Aksakal provides would be the simplest one and in many cases you are going to have a quite satisfying result (but it's still depends on the dataset you have).